# Magento 2 theme install Error

Tags: magento2, admin, cart, theme, admin-panel

I was working on a new Magento-2 (Version-2.3.0) site and all workes is fine then I added theme so my admin was not open and showing this error.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue with your `etc/acl.xml` file.

Please check your custom module or 3rd party extension's `etc/acl.xml` file.

You need to add the `title` attribute in the `etc/acl.xml` and flush the cache will resolve the issue

for example

```
<!-- provided by Magento_Backend, so they already have a title: -->
<resource id="Magento_Backend::stores">
    <resource id="Magento_Backend::stores_settings">
        <!-- provided by Magento_Config: -->
        <resource id="Magento_Config::config">
            <!-- New resource! Title is required: -->
            <resource id="Vendor_Module::config_general" title="Something" translate="title"/> 
        </resource>
    </resource>
</resource>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check all of your custom and third party module code `acl.xml` file to check the missing title.

location of acl file is

> app/code/Vendor/ModuleName/etc/acl.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Acl/etc/acl.xsd">
    <acl>
        <resources>
            <resource id="Magento_Backend::admin">
                <resource id="Magento_Backend::stores">
                    <resource id="Magento_Backend::stores_settings">
                        <resource id="Magento_Config::config">
                            <resource id="Vendor_Modulename::xxx_xxxx" title="Resource Title here" />
                        </resource>
                    </resource>
                </resource>
            </resource>
        </resources>
    </acl>
</config>
```